# Retrieve Campaigns Microsoft Dynamic CRM 3.0

Tags: dynamics-crm

does anybody knows how to get (programmatically - C#) the list (and details) of campaigns on Microsoft CRM 3.0 (using the webservice CRM Service) ??

Any help or documentation link would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody is interested, I found out how to get campaigns from Microsoft CRM 3.0 using the webservice. Here is the code.

```
        fetchFilter += @"<fetch mapping='logical'>";
        fetchFilter += @"<entity name='campaign'><all-attributes/>";
        fetchFilter += @"<link-entity name='systemuser' to='owninguser'>";
        fetchFilter += @"<filter type='and'>";
        fetchFilter += @"<condition attribute='firstname' operator='eq' value='" + firstName + "' />";
        fetchFilter += @"<condition attribute='lastname' operator='eq' value='" + lastName + "' />";
        fetchFilter += @"</filter>";
        fetchFilter += @"</link-entity>";
        fetchFilter += @"</entity>";
        fetchFilter += @"</fetch>";

        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.LoadXml(CrmWebService.Fetch(fetchFilter));
```

Hope it will be useful for somebody.
Bye.